# Connections though firewall

Tags: nginx, nat

I have a nginx server which is right now sitting behind another nginx server. I plan to move this new server to the front and it will start getting aroung 500 req/second. I am looking at some munin graphs and something surely looks suspicious

http://monitor.wingify.com/munin/visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/lb1.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com-fw_conntrack.html

Can you comment, if this is normal or the excessive TIME WAIT is wrong. Also, the response time of this server isnt very good. Feel free to view other munin graphs and comment if anything is not right

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, excessive timewaits are not normal. I would check ur servers timwait config. It will likely be 2 mins. Are you serving a web application? If so, that may be your culprit as you may have a thread leaving the socket prior to receiving a fin packet.  Do you have a loadbalancer? I would look into whether you are receiving the fin packet. You can also run lsof -p  -Tq on the server it will show you what is on the queue. Also running netstart -an will show you this as well by piping the port that is in timewait.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. netstat -an gave me a long list of waiting connections. How can I fix it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, this is a reverse proxy and it acts as a LoadBalancer.